# java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out:could be due to invalid address on IBM AIX

Tags: java, aix, socks

I am facing one weird issue on IBM AIX machine. It's working fine on windows and other unix box. The issue is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out:could be due to invalid address
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:372)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:233)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:220)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:378)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:536)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.jc.connect(jc.java:111)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.jc.<init>(jc.java:359)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:8)
        at InstallCert.main(InstallCert.java:147)
```

I am trying to connect to `wsk.op.fi` it's bank site. 
I am using `InstallCert` program to dowload certificates from `wsk.op.fi:443` using proxy setting

The same program works fine on windows and other unix box. Please help me

Comment: Did you try to traceroute or ping the external host (from AIX box)?

Comment: I tried this telnet wsk.op.fi 443
Trying...and it time out

Comment: So it looks like that you have a general network issue. Ask your network operations team on how to connect to the internet, maybe it's just forbidden by rule?

Comment: But we are able to connect to site https://wsk.op.fi/services/CorporateFileService and that mean we have internet connection but it doesn't work for wsk.op.fi

Comment: So you mean do we need to ask the host that open a new port so that we can connect them

Comment: Maybe, aprox 1,000 different things can go wrong - call your sys admin.

Comment: Thanks..I will get back to you

Comment: The problem is exactly on the handshake part